# Android change data in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I use this adapter for my ListView:

```
Appadapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> 
     private PackageManager pm=null;
     List<ResolveInfo> apps;
     AppAdapter(PackageManager pm, List<ResolveInfo> apps) {
    super(Launchalot.this, R.layout.row, apps);
  this.apps=apps;
  this.pm=pm;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                      ViewGroup parent) {
      Log.w(Launchalot.this.getPackageName(),"getView");
  if (convertView==null) {
    convertView=newView(parent);
  }

  bindView(position, convertView);

  return(convertView);
}

private View newView(ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.w(Launchalot.this.getPackageName(),"newView");
  return(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
}


private void bindView(int position, View row) {
  TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
  Log.w(Launchalot.this.getPackageName(),"bindView");
  label.setText(getItem(position).loadLabel(pm));

  ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);

  icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm));
}
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setNotifyOnChange(true);}}
```

I populate my view using this code in a ListActivity class:

```
AppAdapter adapter=new AppAdapter(getPackageManager(), getResolveInfoList(0));
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now i have changed List apps 
I've called notifyDataSetChanged()
 but, as I think, nothing changed. Please tell me a solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This information is still not enough to see the problem and help you. that's why I will explain with a simple example how to use `notifyDataSetChanged();` on `MyCustomAdapter`.
Here is a example how to populate the adapter:

```
private ArrayList<String> _names;
private MyCustomAdapter _adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _names = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < _names.size();i++){
        _names.add("Element : "+i);
    }

    _adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, _names);
    _myListView.setAdapter(_adapter);


}

private void refreshListView(){
    _names.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < _names.size();i++){
        _names.add("New Element : "+i);
    }
    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The idea here is to change the `List` which you are using to populate your listview. Clear it, populate it with the new data and after that call `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Short and fast, call these two lines after you feel changes have been done in dataset.

```
AppAdapter adapter=new AppAdapter(getPackageManager(), getResolveInfoList(0));
setListAdapter(adapter);
```