# Android TextView: getText() is working but setText is not working

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and my requirement is to set first item as selected (With White Background and Different Text, other list items have grey background). This is the sample code I am using

```
View listFirstItem = myListAdapter.getView(0,null, null);
Log.d(TAG, ((TextView)listFirstItem.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle)).getText()+ "");
((TextView)listFirstItem.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle)).setText("My Text");
listFirstItem.setBackground(getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
```

Interestingly, I am getting correct item title (title of first list item), but when I try to change this title of try to change the color, it does work. I know a work around to achieve desired output, but I want to understand what is the problem with this code.

Comment: I think you have set text finished but textview is not refresh content yet. or still get error then post more detail

Comment: Please post  xml layout where itemTitle is defined

Comment: @GiapLee It doesnt throw any Exception or Error Message.

Comment: @Alex you can try gettext() -> print text to Log -> setText() -> getText() -> print text to Log again to check it have changed or not

Comment: Try to add `myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting text and background color.

Comment: @GiapLee its showing me updated text but not updating it on UI. I have added notifyDataSetChanged as well. but its not working.

Comment: Did you solve it? If you have done please comment or answer I am also stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code as below:

```
View listFirstItem = myListAdapter.getView(0,null, null);
TextView  tv = (TextView)listFirstItem.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
Log.d(TAG, (tv.getText().toString());
tv.setText("My Text");
listFirstItem.setBackground(getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ripple));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a listview! listview for showing data, use from data that you passed to yourAdapter.
you must change your data, and then NotifyDataSetChanged() it.

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662085/5901637)

Comment: Why Notify is required. Incase of ListView Item Click I can update view without Notify and it work perfectly. Why its not happening here.

Comment: @Alex you can't do it... listview update by adapter data, not else way